# Implementing an application using angular and angular material cdk drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular6

I'm trying to implement an app where images can be dragged and dropped and change position with each other freely, without overlapping. I am using play.grafana.org but I can't seem to tackle this problem.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using the new Angular CDK this should be straight forward. A wrapper div using CSS flex will make your images float inside. Add the cdkDrag on the elements containing the images will give you possibility to drag them around. To reorganize the position use the moveItemInArray-function in the drop-event.

The CDK got examples that you can follow and is almost what you are looking for, I guess..